# Out-of-the-box MVC ModelBinder for KendoUI AutoComplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I have not been able to find a way to easily read the ajax posted values sent by the KendoUI AutoComplete widget.

The [documentation](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/serverfiltering.html) is lacking any details on this task. In fact all I could find for a server side code example was the following :

```
namespace Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Controllers
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public partial class AutoCompleteController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ServerFiltering()
        {
            return View();
        }
   }
}
```

I was expecting the incoming data to auto-bind to a `Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest` but this isn't happening ...

Please, if you have efficiently dealt with a KendoUI AutoComplete widget, share your experience, TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@David Perlman, I am completely editing this answer since I now understand your question better. In the `Kendo` example on `Server Filtering` they are using OData which has out of the box server filtering, something I was not aware of myself. If you use an MVC Controller like I do, you will have to modify the example and use a [parameterMap](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) like I will use in my new code example. In my example I have a simple table of "Sites" I use `Entity Framework` and I have a view wired directly to the Sites table. I have a class called Lookups.cs and I return a dynamic model GetSitesStartsWith(string startsWith) Like so:

```
  public dynamic GetSitesStartsWith(string startsWith)
    {
        return _context.vAaiomsSites
            .Select(s => new
            {
                ID = s.ID,
                SiteName = s.SiteName
            }).OrderBy(s => s.SiteName).Where(s => s.SiteName.StartsWith(startsWith));
    }
```

So in my Requisitions controller I create a JsonResult like so:

```
  public JsonResult GetSitesStartsWith(string startsWith)
    {

        var lookups = new Lookups();
        var data = lookups.GetSitesStartsWith(startsWith);
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Last thing to do is add the AutoComplete code to the View that is wired to this JsonResult rather than to OData like so:

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
        <div class="demo-section">
            <h2>Sites</h2>
            <input id="sites" style="width: 250px" />
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#sites").kendoAutoComplete({
                    placeholder: "Enter site ...",
                    dataTextField: "SiteName",
                    filter: "startswith",
                    minLength: 3,
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "json",
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        pageSize: 20,
                        transport: {
                            read:
                                {
                                    url: "Requisitions/GetSitesStartsWith"
                                }, //read
                            parameterMap: function() {// send value of autocomplete as the "startsWith" parameter
                                        return { 
                                               startsWith:$("#sites").data("kendoAutoComplete").value()
                                        };
                            }
                        } //transport
                    } //datasource
                }); //kendoAutoComplete
            }); //DocumentReady
        </script>
</div>
```

I have this example working and it does the filtering on the server, verified with developer tools. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: thanks Alan, the AutoComplete widget on the client side is working just fine ... could you pls show me the MVC method you are using to pick up the ajax call

Comment: @David Perlman, I'm not sure if I understand your question. The only thing MVC is doing here is delivering the View, you are populating the autocomplete with an ajax call after the page loads in the transport section of the code. So for instance in my example once the page loads and you type an "A" the kendo Autocomplete widget will make the ajax call to the url, in this case it is a kendo server they allow access to. You would need to have your own datasource set up to handle the json call. I personally use a controller to return my data but you could use OData or the new Web API. Let me know

Comment: @David Perlman, I added some code for the Controller Action that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Alan, thanks so much once again ... maybe I was a bit unclear in my question. I am looking to do server side filtering rather than load the whole list from start.

Comment: okay! I was not aware of this parameterMap feature. I don't know where it was hiding but it sure adds the flexibility I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an EXCELLENT post describing how to work with Keno Autocomplete within MVC [here](http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/using-kendoui-with-mvc4-webapi-and-odata/).

If you decide to implement the code which is described there be sure to follow it very carefully. 
Any and every discrepancy will probably break Kendo.